# How do I keep screen on in Flutter using FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON?

Tags: android, flutter

I've been trying to work out how to keep the screen on in an app I'm working on.  There is a lot of information about this online, but I haven't really found anything flutter specific.  I've found various post about using wakelocks but when I try that my app always ends up crashing on start.  I'd prefer not to use wakelocks though.

The information that I find tells me to put the following into MainActivity.java.

getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)

When I do this, the app won't compile because of errors with it.

package WindowManager does not exist
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                                      ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

This is the code that I have in MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
}
```

Is there any advice on what I'm missing?

Edit: I was able to get FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON working.  I needed to import android.view.WindowManager in MainActivity.java.  This is what the code looks like now:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager; //Needed for not letting screen shut off.
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

    //Do not let screen shut off.
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  }
}
```

I tried using android:keepScreenOn="true", but could not work out where to put it in my files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use android:keepScreenOn="true". Please take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true">
...
```

Comment: I gave this a try.  I wasn't able to determine exactly where to put it, but tried various places that had similar XML.  It would not compile.  This does seem like it would be the best solution if I could get it to run.

Comment: Put it in parent/root element of xml file of your activity. See the example I provide and read the documentation please.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

This permission will allow you to use wake lock api.